# Track the usage and bill in Azure api-management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

1. Each customer will have a web api application. Is there a way to bill customer as per the usage by deploying it to api-management?

   I have gone through the following article but we are not expecting each customer to have such data requirement to choose Standard/Premium.

   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/api-management/
2. Also, I am confused what the unit means and how pay as you go will work if there are limitations such as ~1 TB/month data transfer. Does ~1 TB denote the maximum usage in this package?

Answer (score 0):

1) if by "bill customer as per usage" you are expecting to capture the number of total backend api invocations through APIM and bill customer based on counts from APIM - yes it is possible. Also you can on-board multiple API's (backend) on a single instance of APIM or onboard the same backend api as 2 api's on APIM and share two different URL's and track usage separately.

2) yes per unit in standard 1 TB is the max. Pay as you go is by the units consumed (and not the number of api calls going through APIM) and a unit has upper ceiling in-terms of no. of calls and data transfer. so yes in short if you choose standard with 1 unit you need to pay 699/month if there are 100 api calls or 1 million (upto max 7 mil per day) going through APIM but you have the flexibility to choose number of units based on volume you need and pay only for that.